# How to make the controller wait for factory response in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get the response from factory to controller. but when i am calling a function of factory from controller, then the controller not waiting for its response. and giving "undefined".

**here it is my controller.js**

```
app.controller('customerCommentsController',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$sce,$timeout,Comments){     

var commentsdata = '';

Comments.init(1,5);

$scope.total_comments = Comments.total();
console.log($scope.total_comments); //undefined 

$scope.positive_comments = Comments.positive();
console.log($scope.positive_comments);  //undefined 

$scope.commentsdata = Comments.getcomments(1,30);       
console.log($scope.commentsdata);   //undefined     
});
```

here I am calling init() method which gets the response from ajax, which   takes some time to execute , but before it could complete, the other 2 statement   (total() and positive() method) execute below the init method. and that not gets   initialize because of init method not completed. and that why I am getting   undefined.
    and same problem is coming when I am calling getcomments method which doesn't wait for its response.

**here it is my factory**

```
app.factory("Comments",function($http,$timeout,$q){

var commentshtml = [];
var commentshtml1 = [];

return {
    init :  function(start,end) {  
    var request = $http({   
            method:"post",
            url:"/comments.php",
            data: {start:start,end:end},                
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
        });     

    request.success(function(data){                 
            commentshtml = data;            
        });             
    },      
    total : function() {

                return commentshtml.total_comment;                    
    },
    positive : function(){

            return commentshtml.per_positive_comment;               
    },
    getcomments : function(start,end) { 

        var promise  = $http({  
            method:"post",
            url:"/comments.php",
            data: {start:start,end:end},                
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
        });

        promise.success(function(data){                 
            commentshtml1 = data.comments;
            console.log(commentshtml1); //giving the object             
            return commentshtml1;   
        }); 

    }
};
```

Comment: you should use a deferred object (see Ignat's answer below) or at least callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

In factory

```
   return {
    init :  function(start,end) {  
     return $http({     //return the promise 
            method:"post",
            url:"/comments.php",
            data: {start:start,end:end},                
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
        });     
    }
  getcomments : function(start,end) { 
             return $http({   //return the promise
            method:"post",
            url:"/comments.php",
            data: {start:start,end:end},                
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
        });

}
```

In Controller

```
Comments.init(1,5).then(function(){
 $scope.total_comments = Comments.total();
console.log($scope.total_comments);  

  $scope.positive_comments = Comments.positive();
console.log($scope.positive_comments);
 });
Comments.getcomments(1,30).then(function(data){
  $scope.commentsdata =data.comments;

})
```

Or the best way use resolve property in ng-route or ui-router

Comment: :- Thanks for your help. It worked for me. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

it's better to use $q module to work with asynchronous functions in angular. Read this docs:

[$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

You are performing asynchronous request, the problem is that you retrieve data before she is defined.

A good practice is to use **promise**. You hace to know that the **$http** service return promises, and has some callback method, like `.success()` and `.then()` for example.

For promise, angular provide us a pretty good tool : **$q.defer()**.

**$q.defer()** is a **promise manager** from the **deferred API**.

`$q.defer()` get 2 methods :

- `resolve(value)` : which resolve our associated promise, by giving her the final value
- `reject(reason)` : which resolve an promise error.

So you can do the following :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Comments) {

  //Retrieve our init promise
  var promise_init = Comments.init();

  //Retrieve our total promise
  var promise_total = Comments.total();

  promise_init.then(function(){
    //Return promise for chaining
    return promise_total;
  }).then(function(total){
    //Retrieve total of comments
    $scope.total = total;
  }).catch(function(err){
    //Catch error of total comments
    $scope.total = err;
  });

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($q){

    var commentshtml = [];

    function init(){
      //Create defer object
      var defer = $q.defer();
      commentshtml = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
      //Simulate latency
      setTimeout(function(){
        //Resolve our promise
        defer.resolve();
      }, 2000);

      //Return a promise
      return defer.promise;
    }

    function total(){
      var defer = $q.defer();
      commentshtml.length < 3
      ? defer.reject('error length')
      : defer.resolve(commentshtml.length);
      return defer.promise;
    }


    return {
      init: init,
      total: total
    };

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Comments', Service);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>

    <h2>Total : {{total}}</h2>

  </body>
```

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WymmE3UNbFR6gxXeQuoB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Write your all `$scope` variable in `then` function.

So your **Controller.js** :

```
app.controller('customerCommentsController',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$sce,$timeout,Comments){     

    var commentsdata = '';

    Comments.init(1,5).then(function(){

         $scope.total_comments = Comments.total();
         console.log($scope.total_comments); //undefined 

         $scope.positive_comments = Comments.positive();
         console.log($scope.positive_comments);  //undefined 

         $scope.commentsdata = Comments.getcomments(1,30);       
         console.log($scope.commentsdata);   //undefined     
    }
});
```

You have to return your `$http` request.

So your init function look like :

```
init : function(start,end) {  
return $http({   
        method:"post",
        url:"/comments.php",
        data: {start:start,end:end},                
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
    }).success(function(data){
          return commentshtml = data;
    });
}
```

And your Factory :

```
app.factory("Comments",function($http,$timeout,$q){

var commentshtml = [];
var commentshtml1 = [];

return {
init :  function(start,end) {  
return $http({   
        method:"post",
        url:"/comments.php",
        data: {start:start,end:end},                
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
    }).success(function(data){
          return commentshtml = data;
    });
},      
total : function() {

            return commentshtml.total_comment;                    
},
positive : function(){

        return commentshtml.per_positive_comment;               
},
getcomments : function(start,end) { 

    var promise  = $http({  
        method:"post",
        url:"/comments.php",
        data: {start:start,end:end},                
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
    });

    promise.success(function(data){                 
        commentshtml1 = data.comments;
        console.log(commentshtml1); //giving the object             
        return commentshtml1;   
    });
```

Comment: bhaskar:- If I use then function , then I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

Comment: Yes because you didn't return factory init function's $http.